# How to call async methods in an Array map or forEach?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

I'm making my first attempts with Swift's async/await features and Task.

My first goal is working with `NSItemProvider`. I have a custom class that extends `NSObject` and conforms to `NSSecureCoding`. I have working code that converts my class to and from `NSItemProvider`.

What I'm now trying to do is convert an array of `NSItemProvider` objects back into an array of `MyClass` objects. Each conversion requires a call to an `async` function.

I'm able to do this using a plain `for in` loop. The trouble begins when I try to use `compactMap` or `forEach` to create the new array from the array of `NSItemProvider`.

Here is some code that can be copied into a Swift Playground or project that demonstrates the issue.

```
import Foundation

class MyClass: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    var name: String

    override var description: String {
        return name
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    static var supportsSecureCoding = true

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let name = coder.decodeObject(of: NSString.self, forKey: "name") as? String {
            self.name = name
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension MyClass {
    static let identifier = "mySpecialId"

    func asItemProvider() -> NSItemProvider {
        return NSItemProvider(item: self, typeIdentifier: Self.identifier)
    }

    static func create(withItemProvider itemProvider: NSItemProvider) async throws -> Self? {
        let res = try await itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: identifier)
        return res as? Self
    }
}

func example() {
    Task {
        let objs = [ MyClass(name: "A"), MyClass(name: "B"), MyClass(name: "C"), MyClass(name: "D") ]
        let providers: [NSItemProvider] = objs.map { $0.asItemProvider() }

        do {
            // This basic `for in` loop works
            var newObjs = [MyClass]()
            for provider in providers {
                if let obj = try await MyClass.create(withItemProvider: provider) {
                    newObjs.append(obj)
                }
            }
            print("newObjs: \(newObjs)")

            // Attempt to use `forEach`
            // Error: Cannot pass function of type '(NSItemProvider) async -> MyClass?' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
            /*
            providers.forEach { provider in
                if let obj = try await MyClass.create(withItemProvider: provider) {
                    newObjs.append(obj)
                }
            }
             */

            // Attempt to use `compactMap`
            // Error: Cannot pass function of type '(NSItemProvider) async -> MyClass?' to parameter expecting synchronous function type
            //let newObjs2 = providers.compactMap { await MyClass.create(withItemProvider: $0) }
        } catch {

        }
    }
}
```

I was looking at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804026/async-await-list-detail) but the solutions are far more complicated than just using a simple `for in` loop.

Is there a simpler way to use `compactMap`, for example, to directly convert the array of `NSItemProvider` into an array of `MyClass`?

Comment: There is no simple way if asynchronous data processing is involved. The async/await way is `TaskGroup`. By the way have a look at the new [`Transferable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreTransferable/Transferable?changes=_3) protocol which is less *objective-c-ish* than `NSItemProvider`.

Comment: @vadian I'll have to look into TaskGroup more. But what I've seen it's a lot more verbose than the `for in` loop I posted in this question. I'll also have a look into Transferable. I'm using `NSItemProvider` for both drag and drop (in collection views, table views, and custom views) as well as with the pasteboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`for in` loop is a lower-level feature built into Swift.

[forEach](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/foreach(_:)) (as well as compactMap) are methods implemented on the Array type. Being a function it expects arguments of a certain type - in the `forEach` case this is `(Self.Element) throws -> Void`

When you call

```
providers.forEach { provider in
    if let obj = try await MyClass.create(withItemProvider: provider) {
         newObjs.append(obj)
    }
}
```

You are passing in a closure of type `(NSItemProvider) async throws -> Void` which is obviously not what the compiler expects and provides a (very informative I must say) error message.

Hopefully soon we will have these functions working 'natively' with async-await. Meanwhile [Sundell](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/async-and-concurrent-forEach-and-map/) might have an idea how to do it if you insist on using this syntax which [could potentially be useless](https://forums.swift.org/t/do-we-want-foreach/56929/2) anyway.